# How to restore the quantity and consumption fields to their original numbers in the Item table after deleting an Order with Items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to restore my `Quantity` and `Consumption` fields to their original  numbers before I added `Items` to my `Order` in my **`Item` table**. So after I delete an `Order`, the `Item` should return to its default `Quantity` and `Consumption` before I added those items.

The problem is that my `Order` and `Item` table are linked through an `OrderItem` table. So, the `code` in the `Delete Post Method` of `Order` won't be that simple. However, I tried to do it in the same way I did when I individually remove `OrderItems` from my `Order`.

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't work, nothing happens to the fields, they just stay the same. Any ideas? If you need any additional code, please let me know.

**Delete  POST method in ORDER**:

```
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{           
 Order order = db.Orders.Find(id);
            var query = from ord in db.OrderItems where ord.OrderItemID == id select ord; // supposed to get the orderitem based on the OrderID
            foreach (OrderItem ord in query)
            {

                var item = from o in db.Items where o.ItemID == orderItem.ItemID select ord; // supposed to get the item linked to that specific orderitem
                foreach (Item o in item)
                {
                    o.Consumption = o.Consumption - orderItem.Quantity; //restores the consumption (aka how much stock was used)
                    o.Quantity = o.Quantity + orderItem.Quantity; //restores the quantity by adding back items that were taken out
                }

            }
            db.Orders.Remove(order);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? error messages? incorrect quantities? does nothing happen at all?

Comment: Nothing happens at all.

Comment: Where you you call `UpdateItem()`?

Comment: I've added the full code for the post method, if thats what you're after?

Comment: Are you able to step through the code and check that the query is returning data and the code is entering the foreach loops?

Comment: Yes, it seems that this line `var item = from o in db.Items where o.ItemID == orderItem.ItemID select ord;` is not pulling the items linked to the order item

Comment: Should it not just be `var item = from o in db.Items where o.ItemID == orderItem.ItemID select o;`?  You've already declare `ord` in the `foreach`, and then you're selecting it from the linq query- looks like a typo.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that now, but still no effect. I think my approach is wrong.

Comment: I see another typo: `var item = from o in db.Items where o.ItemID == ord.ItemID select o;` - you were joining on orderItem rather than the `ord` in the loop

Comment: Alright, made those changes too, but still no change to the values unfortunately.

Comment: try this: `o.Consumption = o.Consumption - ord.Quantity;` I'm suprised you're not getting complation errors, as you're using undeclared vars!

Comment: Same issue, no change to the values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89157/discussion-between-markpsmith-and-mustang00).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise the typos identified in the comments/chat:

Because you have relationships set up, we can use them to get related entities rather than select from the db context every time.

```
// note addition of ToList()
var query = (from ord in order.OrderItems select ord).ToList();
```

and inside the first foreach:

```
var item = from o in db.Items select o;
```